# Simple compression functions an sponge functions for educational purposes

Tags: algorithm-design, merkle-damgaard, sponge, education

For block ciphers, there are the very well designed schemes of Simple-DES and Simple-AES, which have been created not for security but for teaching the design principles of the real algorithms while maintaining the possibility to calculate them by hand and guarantee an easy demonstration.

Are there any such simplified functions for Merkle-Damgard compression functions or sponge functions available?

Comment: Would the simplest MD compression function just be a random s box of say 6 bits size so with 2 no. 3 bit inputs creating a 3 bit chaining value?

Comment: Or would you be looking for a compression function too wide for a pre calculated s box?

Comment: I'm looking for something that is close in style to the real functions (SHA-2, Keccak) but simpliefied to allow an easy presentation in a short timespan. S-AES has all the same steps as the real AES but reduced to a block size of 16 bit and uses only 2 rounds.

Comment: spritz is a lot simpler than sha3, though it still might be a bit much for paper...

Comment: I understand, but I'd add this. The MD construction is really a facilitator for hashing data wider than the native block width of the compression function.  If you specifically want to illustrate the operation of the MD pattern, it doesn't require anything clever for the compression function itself.  The I/O relationship of my 6 bit lookup table will behave similarly to that of a SHA-2 compression function. You'll even have avalanche effect.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the designs in the NIST SHA-3 competition came with toy variants for study.  For example:

- The winner of the competition, Keccak, has parameters for:

  - word size—the SHA-3 standard is 64-bit, but it is formally defined for 1-bit, 2-bit, 4-bit, 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32-bit words too, for study or for smaller variants like [Ketje](https://keccak.team/ketje.html) and [Keyak](https://keccak.team/keyak.html); and
  - number of rounds—the SHA-3 standard is 24 rounds, but that is overkill, so [KangarooTwelve](https://keccak.team/kangarootwelve.html) uses 12 while still providing comfortable collision resistance, and [Kravatte](https://keccak.team/kravatte.html) uses 6 without aiming for collision resistance.
- The popular [BLAKE2](https://blake2.net/) was derived from [BLAKE](https://131002.net/blake/), one of the SHA-3 finalists, which uses [HAIFA](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/278), which is similar to Merkle–Damgård and Davies–Meyer but with improvements, came with several [toy versions](https://131002.net/blake/toyblake.pdf): BLOKE, FLAKE, BLAZE, and BRAKE, each with simplifications on the real BLAKE.  All admit reduced-round variants too, of course.

You could, of course, take any block cipher you like, and apply it with Davies–Meyer, or any of [various block cipher constructions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45708-9_21), and study the result.  One easy target for cryptanalysis might use AES-256 in one of those forms, so that you could apply the [Biryukov–Khovratovich related-key attacks](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/317).