# What is a simple 8-bit cryptographic hash function that I can use in a quantum simulation of Grover's algorithm?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, post-quantum-cryptography

I'm taking a quantum computing course in which, for our final project, we must create a proof-of-concept implementation of Grover Search for finding hash collisions up to a difficulty (similar to blockchain).

I need a (relatively) simple hash function. As this will be running on a quantum simulator, I'm limited in the number of qubits which I can simulate. Ideally, the hash function should output 8-bits for arbitrarily sized input, should not be crackable (trivially, for example by hand), and should be relatively fast as the hash function (although classical) will be implemented with quantum logic gates.

I was considering an 8-bit version of SHA-1, however I'm not sure how adaptable SHA-1 would be in this situation.

Comment: Relevant https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50322/36960

Comment: You could use a Keccak sponge with 1-bit words: 25 total bits of state, so you can use a sponge of capacity 8 for an 8-bit hash.

Comment: Double Pearson, as in two Pearson hashes with separate tables, xored together. A lot simpler than inventing something weird & wonderful.

Comment: An 8-bit hash is going to be very susceptible to collision search: probability that there is a collision among outputs for 20 random distinct inputs is >53% (except if the input space is small and the hash chosen to minimize that probability).

Comment: Note proof-of-work is usually about finding (partial) _preimages_, which Grover's algorithm can do ‘faster’ than classical preimage search.  But for _collision_ search (which is less constrained than partial preimage search, and thus is easier), while one can apply Grover with BHT or tweak Grover with Ambianis, it's not clear that even if you count qubits and qubit operations as if they were bits and bit operations you could get anything cheaper than a classical collision search anyway.  So I took this question to be about _preimage_ search, not collision search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a derivative of the [Pearson Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing). It can be implemented in two forms, using   separate and independent random permutation tables as:-

1. `h1 = T1[h1 ^ x[i]]` , `h2 = T2[h2 ^ x[i]]` and then finally `h = h1 ^ h2`,
2. `h = T1[h ^ x[i]]`  followed immediately by `h = T2[h ^ x[i]]` so effectively you run one lookup table into the other,

where h is the final 8 bit output. The latter form seems cooler and    simpler. Construct the tables `T1` and `T2`  any way you can think of.
 Both methods result in good uniform output distribution with the expected $ 1 \over e $ rate of collisions.  It's well proven, not trivially crackable and extremely simple if you can spare the requisite 512 bytes for the two tables.

---

Note. As pointed out in the comments, free qubits may be scarce. Might it be possible to ignore the storage requirements for the hash algorithm itself?  If the experiment is for "Grover Search for finding hash collisions", you're primarily looking at techniques for breaking the hash not making it. Therefore I would be minded to exclude any storage requirement for making the hashes from the total simulated qubit count. Only you can decide if this is an appropriate compromise.

Comment: The storage requirements may pose a challenge for implementation on a (simulated) quantum computer in which qubits are scarce.

Comment: The whole point of Grover's algorithm is that it can find preimages faster by querying quantum superpositions of the hash function.  If you, say, had the quantum computer ask a classical computer to evaluate the hash on a single point at a time, Grover's algorithm wouldn't work.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Not what I said.  I said add extra qubits to the quantum simulator resources to cater for the hash algorithm, but then don't count them for the purposes of the experiment. I'm suggesting: let quantum gate count($Pearson^2$) = 0. There ain't no classical computer in my cunning/madcap scheme.

Comment: There is a classical computer involved here - the OP is simulating a quantum computer on a classical one. Simulating a quantum computer on a classical computer requires exponential cost. You can't simply tell the simulator "don't count these qubits against the cost" any more than you can do the same for brute forcing a key on a classical computer. Even if you could, I'm not sure doing so in regards to publishing the result would be ethical.

Comment: This is the function I ended up implementing. Compared with SHA-3, Pearson required far fewer qubits as the hash can be built in-place in an output register as opposed to a state register which is used to build the hash in a separate output register. Additionally, the Keccak spec requires ancillary bits for the permutation function which put us well over the resource limit. Our Grover implementation runs at least 4 times as fast with a double Pearson hash as compared to SHA-3.

Comment: For those curious, I implemented Pearson in a hybrid fashion allowing the blockchain "message" (last block hash, transactions, etc) to be arbitrarily long and in a classical form. The nonce, which was appended to the end of the message, took the form of a 12-qubit register. Pearson hashing is applied in two rounds using two different quantum-implemented LFSRs as permuting functions. As the output is built in-place in an 8-qubit register, the entire implementation consumes at most 21 qubits simultaneously (12 for nonce, 8 for register, 1 for validating success via a Hash Difficulty Oracle).

Comment: @DontTurnAround My quantum competency ~ 0 so this might be laughingly obvious, but how can you afford the time/space for 2 no. dynamic LFSRs but not the static permutation tables? Do you simply subsume the time penalty for operating the LFSRs into the hash rate?

Comment: @DontTurnAround The nonce and LFSR points lead me to wonder if what you went with is even a Pearson hash. Also, you may be interested in knowing that you can answer your own question; The information you included in those comments read more like a self-answer than kind of commentary on this answer.

Comment: @PaulUszak I didn't bother to fully comprehend the Keccak f-[b] permutation function since the register size requirements for input/output/state already made SHA3 quite slow without the correct permuting implementation, but if my understanding is correct the permuting function requires 25 additional state bits aside from the state of the sponge. In a quantum implementation, the LSFR is quite inexpensive as it is composed of 9 CNOT gates, which perform the traditional XOR operation in a superposition.

Comment: The time required to execute this LSFR is essentially constant, especially when considering the exponential runtime associated with simulating 25 state bits for the Keccak f-[1] function.

Comment: @EllaRose The nonce is simply appended to the input and its existence is therefore opaque to the hash function. The LFSR is a deterministic psuedorandom function that serves as the permutation table for Pearson. Unfortunately, quantum computing requires all operations to be deterministically reversible. As such, you cannot simply index into a shuffled array to permute, you _must_ take an input register to an output through only operations on itself as to do otherwise is not guaranteed to prevent the loss of quantum information.

Comment: I'm aware that I may answer my own questions, however I would not have chosen Pearson without Paul so I wanted to give him some credit.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement that it not be trivially crackable is already violated by the premise of an 8-bit hash function: for a uniform random 8-bit function it takes an expected 128 trials to find a preimage, and the time for an expected ${\sim}256/n^3$ trials to find the first preimage among $n$ targets if parallelized $n^2$ ways.  But maybe you meant there are no better-than-generic attacks on it.  (Similarly, it takes an expected ~20 trials to find a collision, although it's not clear that collisions are relevant to your application.)

**You could use a Keccak sponge with 1-bit words for a total 25-bit state, 12 rounds, and an 8-bit capacity.**  I don't know 25-bit Keccak admits better-than-generic attacks—I wouldn't be surprised if it did—but it is structurally the same as the Keccak permutation used in SHA-3, with 64-bit words, 1600-bit state, 24 rounds, and either $4\lambda$- or $2\lambda$-bit capacity (respectively, for the fixed-size hashes like SHA3-256, or for the extendable-output functions like SHAKE128) for $\lambda$-bit collision resistance and $2\lambda$-bit preimage resistance.

Right now, the best collision attacks on 1600-bit Keccak[[1]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/128)[[2]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/529) seem to be limited to 6 rounds, which justified the use of 12 rounds for [KangarooTwelve](https://keccak.team/kangarootwelve.html).  There are newer attacks on other aspects of Keccak, but 12 seems like a reasonable margin—and it's not clear that those attacks would be cheaper than Grover.  If all you want is preimage resistance, a $\lambda$-bit capacity should suffice for $\lambda$-bit preimage resistance.

One nice thing about a permutation-based sponge like Keccak is that the fixed permutation is, well, a permutation, so it will require no ancillary qubits to implement; the only need for ancillary qubits will arise from xoring the message into the state to hash it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @SqueamishOssifrage. SHA-3 was the first thing I attempted to implement after seeing your original comment on my post. Unfortunately 25 bits of internal state is far too much as runtime essentially becomes asymptotic around 18 qubits on most hardware. I attempted to implement a variant of SHA-3 which still relied on a Keccak sponge but utilized a quantum XOR shift PRNG as the permuting function. While runnable, it was still far too slow and additionally the simpler permutation function resulted in poor hash distribution.