# Security of a block cipher if double encryption $E_{K_2} \circ E_{K_1}$ is always single encryption $E_{f(K_1,K_2)}$

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, des

If there always existed a $k_3$ such that $\operatorname{DES}(k_2, \operatorname{DES}(k_1, M)) = \operatorname{DES}(k_3, M)$,  how would that affect the security of $\operatorname{DES}$?

Comment: 2-DES is only 57-bit secure because of meet-in-the-middle attack, so k3 would decrease the security by 1 bit.

Comment: why only 1 bit will be affected?

Comment: @DannyNiu That would decrease the security of **2DES** relative to DES by 1 bit. But the question is about the security of DES itself.

Answer (score 3):

This question was tested years ago by Kaliski at. al [Is the Data Encryption Standard a group? (Results of cycling experiments on DES](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/KRS85a.pdf) as;

- Is DES closed under functional composition?

They applied the cycling test and concluded that DES is not a group. Therefore, we don't expect  that $$\operatorname{DES}(k_2, \operatorname{DES}(k_1, M)) = \operatorname{DES}(k_3, M)$$

As noted in the article, if there was such functional composition then a known-plaintext attack with $2^{28}$ would be able to break DES, on average.

Comment: I hope you dont mind, fixed some words in your nice answer.

Comment: @kodlu nope. Thanks.